# Stationary distribution of a vector-autoregressive process

Tags: probability-distributions, stationary-processes

Given a $K\times K$ real matrix $\mathbf{\Phi}$ and given a sequence $\boldsymbol\varepsilon_t$ of multivariate normal variables $\boldsymbol\varepsilon_t\sim \textrm{N}\left(0,\mathbf{\Sigma}\right)$, with $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ a $K\times K$ positive definite symmetric real matrix, which is the stationary distrinbution of

$$
\mathbf{x}_t =\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_t + \boldsymbol\Phi\,\mathbf{x}_{t-1} = \sum_{h=0}^{t}\boldsymbol\Phi^h\,\boldsymbol\varepsilon_{t-h}\qquad?
$$

ps= It is assumed that all the eignevalues of $\boldsymbol\Phi$ belong to the interval $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stationary distribution is Gaussian with $\mathcal{N}(0, \Lambda)$ where the following recurrence relation (known as the Lyapunov equation) holds for $\Lambda$,

$\Lambda = \Phi \Lambda \Phi^\top + \Sigma$.

In the limit, the solution can be expressed as a summation:

$\Lambda = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Phi^k \Sigma \left(\Phi^\top\right)^k$

In MATLAB, you can use [dlyapchol](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dlyapchol.html) to get the numerical solution.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant solution. Are you aware of any books or papers that discuss this issue and maybe present the result formally?